# Mongodb also selects my "where"

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this query

```
$collection->find(array('_id' => new MongoId($gameid)), array('players' => 1));
```

which selects from this structure

```
var gameSchema = new Schema({
  name : String,
  map : String,
  mode : String,
  playerLimit : Number,
  players : [Player],
  isActive : Boolean
});
```

It does work, it selects all players in a selected game. But for some reason it also returns _id.

```
 Array
 (
[_id] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 506f3c93e0b4791a86000001
    )

[players] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [hero] => Neal, the demon
                [state] => in lobby
                [name] => Test Spiller
            )

    )

)
```

This forces me to use two loops, how can i make it look like

```
    array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [hero] => Neal, the demon
                [state] => in lobby
                [name] => Test Spiller
            )

    )
```

Traversing.

```
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'games');
$trav = $collection->find(array('_id' => new MongoId($gameid)), array('players' => 1));
foreach($trav as $player) {
```

Comment: I cannot use $cursor['players'] @ my foreach, which means i have traverse the players array inside the first loop. Never the less, is this really normal mongodb?

Comment: What are you using to loop through the results? And yes, this is the expected result when you use `MongoCollection::find()`

Comment: Results in a "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type MongoCursor as array" either can i use ->players

Comment: Sorry, I can't say I've worked much with Mongo before. Does `$trav = $collection->find(array('_id' => new MongoId($gameid), 'players' => 1));` work?

Comment: You can also try `$trav_array = iterator_to_array($trav); foreach($trav_array['players'] ...)`

Comment: That would be one solution, but would love to query me of it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, all drivers always return the _id when selecting a field. It also can't select a sub-document directly - so you'll need to pluck it out.

Something like this should help:

```
function array_pluck($key, $input) { 
  if (is_array($key) || !is_array($input)) return array(); 
  $array = array(); 
  foreach($input as $v) { 
      if(array_key_exists($key, $v)) $array[]=$v[$key]; 
  } 
  return $array; 
}
```

then you can do this:

```
foreach(array_pluck("players",$trav) as $player){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. That seems stupid to me :(. Your function doesn't work properly tho, as $input will be a MongoCursor object, causing is to always return array.
However i get your point, and i solves my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for any mistakes, haven't used php in a while :p - your driver should have some equivalent of `.toArray()` in the mongo shell, which is what you'll want to call on your cursor to retrieve the array of objects.

Comment: it is not true that a sub-document can't be returned directly - but that's not really relevant here anyway.  And _id:0 (in shell) will say "don't return _id.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky - the only way to select a subdocument would be `$unwind`, which is not in a stable branch (AFAIK) - if there's another way, would you enlighten us? You're right about the `_id:0` though!

Comment: $unwind is part of aggregation framework which was released into production in late August as 2.2.  It's only relevant to aggregation queries. It's possible to use normal projection to find to get just a subdocument.

Answer (score 0):

You normally get _id returned as part of a MongoDB query unless you explicitly exclude it. I'm not familiar with the PHP syntax, but it looks like you could try adding `_id => 0`

Comment: This removes the _id, but i still have the same issue, as players still isn't the root element.